# Updating grub2 to recognize new windows installation on separate SSD

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning

I currently have a dual boot system on an HDD with Windows 10 and Ubuntu with Grub2.

I just bought an SSD and did a fresh install of windows 10 on it. After the installation, my computer would boot directly into the new windows without the grub menu. However I was able to recover the grub menu by giving boot priority to the HDD in the bios, but now I can't boot into the SSD.

I would like to update the grub menu so I can boot between any of the three OS's.

I tried running `update-grub` but it did not detect the windows installation on the SSD. Yet I can access the SSD file system in ubuntu.

Is there a way to update the grub boot menu so it detects the new installation?

Comment: Are both systems installed in same boot mode, or both UEFI or both BIOS. The boot modes are incompatible and if not same you will not be able to boot Windows from grub, just from UEFI? Also if Windows 10 fast start up on, grub2's os-prober may not be able to see the Windows install. May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Thanks, I tried Boot Repair, clicked "Recommended repair" and got this this message: "The current session is in Legacy mode. Please reboot the computer, and use this software in an EFI session. This will enable this feature. For example, use a live-USB of Boot-Repair-Disk-64bit (www.sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd), after making sure your BIOS is set up to boot USB in EFI mode." I will make a bootable USB and try again

Comment: Do not run autofix, until someone has looked at report. Ubuntu only has one version. How you boot it from the live installer is then the install mode it is in. Both Windows & Ubuntu install in boot mode that you use for installer UEFI or BIOS, but you need to be consistent. Computers since Windows 8 in2012 are UEFI as that was a Microsoft requirement that Windows be installed by vendor in UEFI mode.

Comment: ok, I generated the BootInfo report. Here is the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/WRmJNB7knH/

Comment: Mixed boot issue. You have Windows in UEFI/gpt on sda and Ubuntu and old (?) Windows in BIOS/MBR boot mode in sdb. But also Ubuntu UEFI and ESP on sdb. Windows has to have MBR(msdos) with boot flag on partition with its boot filesyour sdb1, but for UEFI you have to have boot flag on ESP or sdb5 and you cannot have two boot flags. Which Windows are you using? Best to have Windows on sda and Ubuntu in UEFI mode with gpt partitioning on sdb. But conversion to gpt will erase sdb. You may convert MBR to gpt, but sdb Windows will then not boot. Whatever you do backup sdb first.

Comment: I'm using windows 10. I'm willing to completely erase everything on sda and reinstall windows since I don't have any personal data on there anyway. I can try to back up stuff from sdb onto an external HD. So if I were to erase everything, how would I go about installing windows on sda, and then restoring ubuntu on sdb in a way that they are both in the same boot mode where I can dual boot?

Comment: Are you willing to erase Windows on sdb? Or at least back it up and separately backup all data? I prefer UEFI for newer systems. Microsoft has required vendors to install Windows in UEFI mode since Windows 8 released in 2012, but Windows has CMS or BIOS boot mode for those who want the 35 yr old BIOS/MBR configuration. I would erase sdb and install Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode. Or you may be able to convert sdb to gpt (Windows on sdb would then not be bootable) and install Ubuntu in UEFI mode to sdb.

Comment: So by merely erasing everything on sdb and doing a clean install of Ubuntu on there it should fix the problem? How would I know that Ubuntu is going to install in UEFI mode?

Comment: Is it possible to backup/restore my ubuntu partition exactly how it is? I've had to mess with tons of stuff to get everything working and I have a lot of dev tools and programs installed that I don't want to have to go through again from scratch.

Comment: How you boot install media, is how it installs: Shows installer with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI  I prefer not to attempt to restore Ubuntu, but restore apps  from exported list & restore /home where all user settings are. If system settings you may want /etc and if server apps those specific folders in  / (root).   I use rsync. http://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem